# Significato di "disciogliente" in questo contesto

Tags: word-meaning

Nella versione in italiano dell'episodio *Maria alla croce* di *Mistero buffo*, di Dario Fo, ho letto:

> Gabriele, Gabriele... Gabriele... giovane di dolce figura, per primo tu, tu!, mi hai tradita! Con la tua voce da viola innamorante sei venuto a dirmi che sarei divenuta Regina, io... e beata, io, e gioconda, io... a capo di tutte le donne!
>   Guardami, guardami come sono a pezzi e sbertucciata... l’ultima donna al mondo mi sono scoperta! E tu... tu lo sapevi nel portarmi l’annunzio **disciogliente**, che mi ha fatto fiorire nel ventre questa mia creatura, che sarei arrivata a 'sto bel trono regina!

Ho cercato alla voce "disciogliere" in parecchi dizionari, ma non ho saputo trovare niente che abbia senso in questo contesto. Per questa ragione vi chiedo: 
potreste spiegarmi cosa significa "disciogliente" in questo brano?

Comment: Ho visto che esistono parecchie edizioni di *Mistero Buffo*. In [questo copione di scena](http://bpfe.eclap.eu/eclap/axmedis/a/a13/00000-a13f820a-e123-4de3-b0d4-aac54e6eb726/2/~saved-on-db-a13f820a-e123-4de3-b0d4-aac54e6eb726.pdf) pubblicato in precedenza (2000) al libro che sto leggendo (2003) appare l'espressione "che fa sciogliere di commozione". Quindi penso che sia questo il significato.